# How to vertical align in a div WITH overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow, hidden

i know that there is a lot of tutorials about verticaly align text inside a div, but i need to do that with "overflow:hidden", but it only works with "display: block", not with "display: table-cell".
Here is the html: http://melondev.com.br/twitter/
(Take a look at the long text, even with "overflow: hidden" they continue to go...)
Thanks!

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` only works with `inline` elements. You'll have to calculate the height of the text in js and vertically center it according to the container's dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just apply `overflow: hidden` to the cotaining element.

Strictly speaking, having an element with `display:table-cell` that is not inside an element with `display:table-row` which itself is not inside an element with `display:table` will frequently lead to unpredictable results and unexpected behaviour, this being one of them. Instead, you could easily have used a `<table>` element like this:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100px; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: middle;">Text here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above works! You could also have rows for your note header and stuff. Sure, it's not pretty, but it uses things that were designed for this situation.

But that aside, you have `<div>` elements *inside* a `<span>` - this is not good and many older browsers (and some recent) will reject it. You should never have block-level elements inside an inline-level one.

Comment: You didn't exactly do what I told you, but it worked. In the grand scheme of things, that's acceptable.

Comment: So, what do i have to do? i ALWAYS confuse things when "align" verticaly things in html..

Comment: Well you didn't put `table-layout: fixed` in the table, and you hacked around with `!important`. You also ignored my suggestion to use table rows instead of divs for the elements that make up the note.

Comment: I inserted it in the style.css .twitter_postit .pi_text table and .twitter_postit .pi_text table td... just to simplify js,

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but you DID NOT PUT the styles I told you to use.

Comment: <code>.twitter_postit .pi_text table{
 table-layout: fixed;
 height:140px;
 width:180px;
}
.twitter_postit .pi_text table td{
 width: 190px;
 overflow: hidden;
 vertical-align: middle;
}</code>

Comment: You are still using `!important` when you have no reason to be using it. There should be no width or height on the table, it's the cell that defines that.

Comment: Now its all in the same table, but without inserting the "width" of the table, doesen't work. why?

Comment: is there anything else to change? Thanks!